# Extending/Modifying AddressInterface

Tags: php, oop, interface, sylius

I'm working with `sylius/sylius-standard`. I'm also creating my own bundle with some new entities and models. One of the requirements is to extend/modify the current Sylius Address model, but I've noticed that the [AddressInterface](http://api.sylius.org/Sylius/Component/Addressing/Model/AddressInterface.html) has several methods that I don't want to use, like all those related to FirstName, LastName and Company. As far as I understand OOP and PHP interfaces, my new class or interface should implement all the methods declared in the interface (according to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)).

Is there a way that I could make use of all the functionality that the Sylius Address model provides but with my own `CustomAddressInterface`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your issue is the misunderstanding of what interfaces are.

Interface is a contract. If a class is declared to expects an instance, with as specific interface, it means, that this class is written with intention to use methods from that interface.

If you are using a library, where some code requires a specific interface, then you **have to** implement all of the methods, that it contains. Otherwise your custom class instance will not be able to fulfill the declared contract.

> <sub>**NOTE:** if you are seeing code, that declares to require an interface,
>    but does not actually use all of the methods in that interface, that codebase is violating [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).</sub>

#### Edit

I guess I have to spell it out:

> Is there a way that I could make use of all the functionality that the Sylius Address model provides but with my own CustomAddressInterface?

**No.**

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I'd like some ideas on how to achieve this in Sylius.